# Why is the wrong form opening when I click the doc link I created from a SSJS function?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Ok, this is weird.  I created an xpage input form.  After the form is filled out, a document is created.  I then create an email to notify people that the document has been created.  I drop a doclink to the newly created document in the body of the email.  During testing, I noticed that when I click the link in the email, the wrong Notes Form is opened.  Instead of the 'TrainingRequest' form displaying the fields, the form 'Feedback' opens up instead.  Here's what I checked:

```
- On the xpage data section, the 'form' is set to 'TrainingRequest'.
- When I open the document via the doc link, the field 'form' has the value 'TrainingRequest', which is correct.  Yet it's displaying the 'Feedback' form.
- When I check the other field properties of the document, all the correct fields from the 'TrainingRequest' form are there and populated correctly.  
- When I open the document via the view, the correct Notes form 'TrainingRequest' opens.
- There is no default form in the database design.
```

Has anyone seen this before?

thanks
clem

Comment: Does the default view of your database have a form formula?

Comment: @Torsten  Nice catch!  :-)  Yes, my default view is the Feedback view and had a form formula.  I removed it and now the link works as expected.   Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doc links are always created using the default view of your application. If there is a form formula in this view then this overrides the form in the document. Remove the form formula of the default view and it works.

I almost NEVER use form formulas in my application because of the side effects.

Comment: I rarely use form formulas.  In fact, this might have been the only case ever (which is why it didn't even occur to me to check that).  I had added that many years ago, don't even remember why.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Source code would be useful. But initial best guess based on what you're saying is you have two datasources on the XPage, neither have ignoreRequestParams set, so you're editing the same document with both data sources. ignoreRequestParams missing will ignore any properties you define.

Comment: HI Paul, Thanks for the reply.  No, there are no other data sources.  This is a very simple xpage -- one data source, a few fields to fill out, some code to send the email.  Here's where I attach the doc link:


    body.addNewLine(2);
    body.appendText("Open the request using the following link: ");
    body.addNewLine(2);
    body.appendDocLink(trainingDoc.getDocument());
    body.addNewLine(2);
    body.appendText("Thank you,")

clem